# Sql query to get Average Sales of each product for the last n period

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table of showing sales of various products for different dates. The format would be like

```
Date       | Product | Sales
-----------+---------+-------------
01/01/2016 |    B    |250.00
-----------+---------+-------------
01/01/2016 |    A    |1050.00
-----------+---------+-------------
02/01/2016 |    A    |925.00
-----------+---------+-------------
04/01/2016 |    B    |741.00
-----------------------------------
```

I am looking for a query to get the average sales of each product for the past N days. This query is for use in VB.Net application. Please help me with a query to get the data, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do this:

```
SELECT AVG(t.Sales) as average_col
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL n DAY)
```

Replace `n` with your variable/value .

**EDIT:** For last `N` records :

```
SELECT t.product, AVG(t.Sales) as average_col
FROM YourTable t
Group by t.product
ORDER BY t.date DESC
LIMIT n
```

Comment: Sorry a slight change required instead of N days, I am looking for average for past N records

Comment: Thanks @sagi... i had tried a query similar to this and this one too, but it would give average of all the sales, but my requirement is average of each product

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (where n = 10)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY);
```